# Free hosted wiki for small teams

Tags: gratis, wiki, hosted

I am looking for a wiki with the following features:

- Online & free
- For small teams (from 5 to 15-20 people)
- Internal usage only (so not public access unless you have an account)
- Able to edit documents like Microsoft Word (WYSIWYG)
- Manage spreadsheets
- Able to export the content in reusable formats like Markdown, DOC,
  text etc. to avoid locked-in situations

Is there anything like that?

Comment: do you want web script like wikimedia?

Comment: Are you looking for software for self-hosting?

Comment: To answer both, Wikimedia like could be good, but I don't want to install it, I want it as service in some free website (like google doc)